# Picklist values activate or deactivate with workflow or process builder

Tags: workflow, process-builder, picklist

I am working on the Opportunity Record and we would like to have a more granular reason as to why a Product Opp was lost to a competitor. The business folks want a single picklist but this picklist has to have two separate selection values based on Renewal Business or New Business with SOME overlap.

In other words, for Renewal, the selections are (A, B, C, D, E, F, K) while New Busiess would have (A, B, G, H, I, J, F).

I was thinking this could be accomplished through process builder but that doesn't seem to have the options to activate or deactivate picklist values. Workflows seem to be a good answer here but I am not certain.

Any ideas would be grealty appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are 'Renewal Business' and 'New Business' record types? If so you can [customize which picklist values apply to each record type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=editing_picklists_for_record_types_and_business_processes.htm&type=5)

Comment: Awesome ... just not sure how to do that. Sorry .. I see the link and will see what I can do.

Comment: And they are not record types, but the Type of Opp. Type is a picklist. I THINK that is the record type, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Renewal Business and New Business are not record types, then I recommend looking into '[Dependent Picklists](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm&type=5)'. You can create a new picklist that is dependent on 'Type' and has different selectable values based on the option selected in 'Type'. No need to use workflows or process builder for this.

Comment: I just confirmed with my colleague that the Type field (Renewal or New Business) is NOT a record type.

Comment: I updated my answer given that it is Type and not Record Type

Comment: And that worked. I forgot about those. Thank you!